# PHPの時間設定が反映されない

Tags: php, wordpress

ワードプレスの時刻が９時間ずれており、色々と修正を行ってみているのですが、うまくいきません。
php.iniの設定はAsia/Tokyoになっているようです。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

そこで、以下のようなPHPを実行しました。

```
echo date_default_timezone_get();
echo '<br>';
echo date("Y/m/d - M (D) H:i:s");
echo '<br>';

date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
echo '<br>';
echo date_default_timezone_get();
echo '<br>';
echo date("Y/m/d - M (D) H:i:s");
echo '<br>';

date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Tokyo');
echo '<br>';
echo date_default_timezone_get();
echo '<br>';
echo date("Y/m/d - M (D) H:i:s");
```

すると以下のようになります。
（実行時の正しい日本時間は12:34です。）

```
Asia/Tokyo
2020/07/17 - Jul (Fri) 03:34:48

UTC
2020/07/17 - Jul (Fri) 03:34:48

Asia/Tokyo
2020/07/17 - Jul (Fri) 03:34:48
```

初めの取得される時間がそもそも９時間ずれており、
その後、date_default_timezone_setで変更しているのですが、
設定は変更されているのに時間が変わりません。
UTC+9などの記載にしても同じでした。

何かPHPの設定がよくないのでしょうか...

-------追記------
フォーマットにe,Zを追加しました。オフセットが0になっているということですかね...

```
Asia/Tokyo
2020/07/17 - Jul (Fri) 04:06:03 Asia/Tokyo 0

UTC
2020/07/17 - Jul (Fri) 04:06:03 UTC 0

Asia/Tokyo
2020/07/17 - Jul (Fri) 04:06:03 Asia/Tokyo 0
```

Comment: date関数のフォーマット文字にタイムゾーンも出力するとどうなりますか？（eとZ）

Comment: 追記しました。オフセットがなぜか0になっているということですかね...

Comment: PHPとしてどのタイムゾーンが利用できるかは　https://www.php.net/manual/ja/datetimezone.listidentifiers.php　こちらの関数で確認できます。またそれぞれのオフセットの確認は　https://www.php.net/manual/ja/datetimezone.getoffset.php　で確認できます。これらがきちんと表示されていないとなるとPHPとOSの関係かもしれないですね。

Comment: なるほど...getoffsetが0になりますね...
ありがとうございます。